# how to bound uiimagegview moving in particular portion

Tags: ios4, uiimage, touchesmoved

I am working on an application in which I am adding the same image again and again on a button click on random positions and moving those images.

But on moving those images, images can move in whole view inspite of moving in UIView i want my image to move only in subview(UIImage view) on which i am adding it.

here is my code of TouchesMoved

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

UIImageView *imgPimple;// = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
imgPimple = (UIImageView*)[touch view];

CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:imgPimple superview];

if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])

{
    imgPimple.center = touchLocation;
}

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you having trouble with something in particular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you *should* be doing is:

```
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:[imgPimple superview]];
```

I *think*.

It seems to me that if you're deciding where to move it in its superview, and you get the touch location in the imgPimple view, it will behave incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks for your code, image is moving but problem is it is moving on the whole view but i want to bound image moving. Pls help.

Comment: can you please suggest me how can i move the images only in subView and not in UIView.